# Resize FCKeditor like textarea resize

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I'm Using Fckeditor 2.6 version I been looking for way to resize it much like how traditional textarea look like over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_maxlength)

I'm been googling around for hour now but haven't find anything yet, stumbling upon few solutions (before SO question) but cant seem to find any of them working too.

Any one as a clue?

**FCKEDITOR VERSION : 2.6**

Comment: Wow, that is one old version. Just curious; why not update?

Answer (score 0):

FCKEditor is a six-year-old piece of software, which is no longer supported. It's ancient! Update to CKEditor and enjoy [built-in, configurable editor resizing](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/resize.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this:

```
iframe { resize: both; }
```

(For me, the FckEditor appears inside an iFrame.)

Note that this is not supported by many mobile browsers, or IE (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)